# Want to add a class to a list with specific ID using button

Tags: php, html

The final lists are looking like this and by clicking the green button I need to add class only to the list above. Only PHP is allowed

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiMyI.png)

```
<ul class='wrapper'> 
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>
    <li class="note" id='<?= $item['id'] ?>'>
        <div class="details">
            <p><?= $item['title']."<span class='currentDate'>".$item['currentDate']."</span>"?></p>
            <p class ="importance"><?= $item['importance'] ?></p>
            <div class="border"></div>
            <span><?= $item['text'] ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <span>Do: <?= date('d.m.Y', strtotime($item['date'])) ?></span>

            <form method="post">
            <button name="doneButton" value='<?= $item['id'] ?>' type="submit">✅</button>
            </form>

            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['doneButton'])) {
                    //
                    

                    

                    //
                }
            ?>

            <form method="post" >
            <button value="<?= $item['id'] ?>" name="deleteButton" type="submit">️</button>
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['deleteButton'])){
                    db_remove_note($_POST['deleteButton']);
                    header("Location: list-notes.php");
                }
            ?>
            
        </div>

    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I want to add a class to li with the specific ID ($item['id']) using that doneButton. I need to use PHP only, with no JavaScript or MySQL.

Comment: "Only PHP is allowed" is a very dumb requirement. If you are asking us to do your homework for you, its polite to tell us this.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, but you have an option to help or go back to do your tings so nobody asked if something is or isnt a dumb requirement. Alhamdulillah

Answer (score 0):

Just add the condition to the `li` class attribute. I’d personally use a ternary operator as below to add MYNEWCLASS on the condition that `$_POST['doneButton'])` is set:

```
<li class="note<?=(isset($_POST['doneButton'])?" MYNEWCLASS":"");?>" id='<?= $item['id'] ?>'>
```

EDIT: To select an `LI` by a certain ID:

```
<?php
<ul class='wrapper'> 
<?php foreach ($items as $item) : ?>

    <?php
        $class = ""; //Declare an empty $class
        if (isset($_POST['doneButton']) && $_POST['doneButton'] == $item['id']){
            // If $_POST['doneButton'] is set, and $_POST['doneButton'] is equal to the id of the current iteration then set $class to "MYNEWCLASS"
            $class = " MYNEWCLASS"; //THE SPACE IS IMPORTANT
        }
    ?>

    <li class="note<?=$class;?>" id='<?= $item['id'] ?>'>
        <div class="details">
            <p><?= $item['title']."<span class='currentDate'>".$item['currentDate']."</span>"?></p>
            <p class ="importance"><?= $item['importance'] ?></p>
            <div class="border"></div>
            <span><?= $item['text'] ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-content">
            <span>Do: <?= date('d.m.Y', strtotime($item['date'])) ?></span>

            <form method="post">
            <button name="doneButton" value='<?= $item['id'] ?>' type="submit">✅</button>
            </form>

            <form method="post" >
            <button value="<?= $item['id'] ?>" name="deleteButton" type="submit">️</button>
            </form>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST['deleteButton'])){
                    db_remove_note($_POST['deleteButton']);
                    header("Location: list-notes.php");
                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: i tried that as well, but if i refresh the site or click another button, its a problem

Comment: That would add the class to every `<li>` in the loop though, not a specific one

Comment: That is correct, it will only insert the class when the post data exists. If you refresh, then the post data will be lost. You’ll have to look at storing data in a session if you want to persist the data.

Comment: yes of course, is there therefore any other option? by choosing particular list and add it to it?